# Meaning of "taught us only by a broken heart" in "The Negro's Complaint" by William Cowper

Tags: phrase-meaning, poetry

From *[The Negro's Complaint](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Negro%27s_Complaint)* by William Cowper:

> By our blood in Afric wasted,
>     Ere our necks received the chain;
>   By the miseries that we tasted,
>     Crossing in our barks the main;
>   By our sufferings, since ye brought us
>     To the man-degrading mart,
>   All sustain'd by patience, **taught us
>
>     Only by a broken heart**;
>
> Deem our nation brutes no longer,
>     Till some reason ye shall find
>   Worthier of regard, and stronger
>     Than the colour of our kind.
>   Slaves of gold, whose sordid dealings
>     Tarnish all your boasted powers,
>   Prove that you have human feelings,
>     Ere you proudly question ours!

I don't understand the meaning of the bolded phrase. Who taught whom?

A broken heart taught the slaves? This sounds odd.

I can't come up with any explanation. I would vaguely understand "taught us only **of** a broken heart" (these sufferings taught us to have a broken heart). But this **by** leaves me baffled.

Comment: In your context, *patience, taught us \ Only by a broken heart* could be paraphrased as *patience, which we have learned only **through** bitter experience*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - ah, now it clicks together. Thank you! You could post that as an answer!

Comment: I haven't actually voted on this question, but I think that if you're going to tackle challenging texts like this *in a foreign language*, you must expect to do some of the "interpretation" yourself. If we replaced *by a broken heart* with, say, ***by a crazy preacher***, I don't suppose you'd have had any problem. But hopefully you can see that in *taught [to] us **by** X*, the preposition ***by*** has exactly the same significance regardless of whether *X* is *a broken heart* or *a crazy priest* - it always means *X* is the "teacher", not the "lesson" being taught.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I understand the meaning of **by**, but I missed the fact that it is **patience** that **was taught to us** only by a broken heart. No matter how much I read, I'll always have snags like this. I was not thinking of "to us" but thought that someone/something "taught us". I hope I explained it well enough. O_O Multitasking..

Comment: @TRomano: Sure - it's possible to subdivide what I called the "teacher" (linguistically, the "agent") into *doer, means, manner, method*. But in all versions of *I was taught [something] **by** X*, there's a clear distinction between *something = the lesson, **what** I was taught*, and *X = the method or agent **doing the teaching***.

Comment: @CowperKettle We are all taught by experience :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your passage

> taught us only by a broken heart

means

> taught by way of a broken heart

which is a bitter and disappointing way to learn a life's lessons.

To say

> taught us only **of** a broken heart

would be to learn *about* a broken heart.

But your passage says that it was "*through* a broken heart", or "by *having* a broken heart" that the lessons were learned.